# Code works in Codepen, but not with my desktop files

Tags: javascript, html, codepen

I'm trying to run a simple few lines of code using an index.html file and a script.js file, nothing else.

In the HTML file, I have doctype html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="content1">This is content 1  </div>
  <div id="content2">This is content 2  </div>
  <div id="content3">This is content 3  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And for my javascript section i have:

```
var elems = $("div");
if (elems.length) {
  var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
    if (i !== keep) {
      $(elems[i]).hide();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this in CodePen, or even on the code editor on this website, it works fine. But it doesn't work when I use the files on my desktop (index.html, script.js  I do believe the folder structure is correct (script.js is in the javascript folder.)

Thank you all

Comment: If the code is working on codepen, then it clearly isn't a problem with the code.Try checking the files in the chrome dev tools (ctrl+shift+i, Sources tab) and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 8):

Move your script tag just before the closing of the body tag:

```
<script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This way the DOM will be available when your script runs.

If you prefer to keep your script in the `head` part, then wrap your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var elems = $("div");
    if (elems.length) {
      var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        if (i !== keep) {
          $(elems[i]).hide();
        }
      }
    }
});
```

... so to have your code run when the DOM is ready.

You did not tag your question with `jquery`, but as you seem to use it, you can use this shorter code for doing essentially the same as above:

```
$(function() {
    var $elems = $("div").hide(),
    $elems.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $elems.length)).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code in this function to execute it if the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
// your code goes here
 });
```

Comment: Can you set it as the accepted answer if this code was the solution?